# Using a nested list to create dictionary where first list is column and each list a row?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a nested loop that has the first list as column names and each subsequent list is a row. For example, I have a nested list that gives a person's age and 1 or 0 indicating whether or not they like the color:

```
data = [['age', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'orange'], 
         [12, 1, 0, 0, 1],
         [10, 0, 1, 0, 1],
         [9, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [8, 1, 0, 0, 0],
         [13, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

I want an output that looks like:

```
 new_data ={(12, 'blue'): 1,
            (12, 'green'): 0,
            (12, 'red'): 0,
            (12, 'orange'): 1,
            (9, 'blue'): 0,
            (9, 'green'): 1,
            (9, 'red'): 0,
            (9, 'orange'): 1 .....}
```

etc but with all data.

I've gotten as far as:

```
ages = data[0][1:len(data[0])]

i = 1
for x in ages:
    print({t[0] + x: t[i] for t in data[1:len(data)]})
    i = i + 1
```

and when I try to combine t[0] and x as a tuple it ends up only giving me:

```
{'12blue': 1, '10blue': 0, '9blue': 0, '8blue': 1, '13blue': 1}
{'12green': 0, '10green': 1, '9green': 0, '8green': 0, '13green': 1}
```

etc.

Comment: What if there are three twelve year olds, one of whom doesn't like blue, but the other two do. What should the value for `(12, blue)` be in that case? 1? 0? 0.66?

Comment: It's just based on the data given where there is only one list per age in the data

Comment: These names are not defined: `age, blue, green, red, orange`. Are they supposed to be strings?

Comment: Your output also shows the ages are strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import pprint

data = [['age', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'orange'],
        [12, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [10, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [9, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [8, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [13, 1, 1, 1, 0]]

colors, *rows = data # split in colors and rows

d = {}
for row in rows: 
    idi, *marks = row # split in id and marks
    for color, mark in zip(colors[1:], marks): # iterate in parallel over marks and colors
            d[(idi, color)] = mark


pprint.pprint(d)
```

**Output**

```
{(8, 'blue'): 1,
 (8, 'green'): 0,
 (8, 'orange'): 0,
 (8, 'red'): 0,
 (9, 'blue'): 0,
 (9, 'green'): 0,
 (9, 'orange'): 0,
 (9, 'red'): 0,
 (10, 'blue'): 0,
 (10, 'green'): 1,
 (10, 'orange'): 1,
 (10, 'red'): 0,
 (12, 'blue'): 1,
 (12, 'green'): 0,
 (12, 'orange'): 1,
 (12, 'red'): 0,
 (13, 'blue'): 1,
 (13, 'green'): 1,
 (13, 'orange'): 0,
 (13, 'red'): 1}
```

Comment: This works great thanks! Can you explain what the asterisk is doing? I've looked it up but can't get a clear understanding.

Comment: @mjoy the asterisk is [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) in this case is equivalent to `colors, rows = data[0], data[1:]`